# Rails Active Record: has_many error (NameError: uninitialized constant)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord

Edited:
solved with

```
has_many :imagens, :class_name => 'Imagem', :dependent => :delete_all
```

---

The problem I am facing looks a lot like this one: [Rails : uninitialized constant error on Active Record destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727801/rails-uninitialized-constant-error-on-active-record-destroy)

My iflections file has the following:

```
inflect.plural 'imagem', 'imagens'
inflect.singular 'imagens', 'imagem'
```

When I try to get the images, it raises and error:

```
veiculo = Veiculo.first
veiculo.imagens #uninitialized constant Veiculo::Imagen
```

I don't know why this happens

```
class Veiculo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :caracteristicas, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :imagens, :dependent => :delete_all
  # more irrelevant code
end

class Imagem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :veiculo
  # more irrelevant code, has attached file
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem just now and found the answer: rails' conventions. You need to follow them when creating your models AND when using has_many :through / belongs_to in them.

```
class Imagem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :veiculo
  # more irrelevant code, has attached file
end
```

It should be:

```
belongs_to :veiculos
```

Because "veiculo".pluralize gives us "veiculos" (you can test this in your console!). This should avoid the need of :class_name, which I personally don't like. :)

Also, in case you missed it (I did, twice), you need to use singular names in your relationship table, like belongs_to :veiculo and belongs_to :imagem.